# Let $A$ be a vector and $B$ an $n \times n$ matrix. What does it mean to do $(A^T)BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning

I see a lot of textbooks trying to maximise $(A^T)BA$, where $A$ is a vector and $B$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

I tried looking up in a few textbooks, but all I find is an assertion that minimising distance implies maximising the above

What does it do? what does it mean?

Thank you

Comment: This can be understood by checking any resource on linear algebra. Please make some effort to look a bit by yourself before asking questions here.

Comment: can you point me to any good resource, I have been trying on google but cant find any.

Comment: called a quadratic form. Over the reals, $A$   will usually be symmetric.

Comment: Check https://www.geneseo.edu/~aguilar/public/assets/courses/233/main_notes.pdf and look at what transposes are.

Comment: At the risk of being rude, if you don't even know what the transpose means, why in the world would you possibly want to know this? If you don't know basic linear algebra notation and definitions, then you are not in a position to understand the argument that this is being used in, the applications of the result, or the general context.  If you looked things up in textbooks and didn't understand, its because you need to read the whole textbook and not just the small section, because these things cannot be understood in a vacuum.

Comment: If you're asking what the $T$ means, it just means you're transposing $A$.

Comment: Im sorry if I wasn't clear, Im not asking what transpose means, I am asking the transformation A^T B A, does, in a geometric sense, I can calculate them by multiplying the three, but I want to know the intuition. For example, there is a similar looking expression for Mahalanobis dist. which is a measure of distance. I want to know what the transformation in  question means geometrically

Comment: @raghuramkishoreparupudi It is nowhere said that in your post. Please update it and ask a proper and precise question. Also, if this is a map, define what is the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at linear and quadratic approximation and quadratic programming.
$$ \mathbf{a}^T B \mathbf{a}  $$ is called a quadratic form. Since you mention minimization, what you may have seen is the objective function for quadratic programming
$$
\mathbf{a}^T B \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{a}
$$
which is minimized subject to some possible constraints such as $M\mathbf{a} \leq \mathbf{b}$.
For example, the first couple of terms of a Taylor expansion (2D) produce the Hessian quadratic form:
$$
f(\vec{x} + \Delta \vec{x}) \simeq f(\vec{x}) + 
 \nabla^T f(x) \Delta \vec{x} + 
\frac{1}{2} \Delta \vec{x}^T H \Delta \vec{x} + \dots
$$